# Mapbox Direction GL - show/hide driving instructions

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am hiding driving instructions by default:

```
 var directions = new MapboxDirections({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            controls: { instructions: false }
        });
```

I want to have ability to display/hide it on button click and not sure how it needs to be done.

Comment: You will need to do some more of your own research before asking a question here. Read all of the Mapbox-GL-JS and MapboxDirections documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mapbox-gl-directions`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions) plugin does not provide a setter method for the `options.controls.instructions` parameter. In other words, the boolean value specified at creation of the `MapboxDirections` instance cannot be toggled using a button. All instance members for `MapboxDirections` are documented in [`API.md`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md).

You could experiment with implementing this custom functionality yourself by forking the plugin or opening a pull request to add a `MapboxDirections#setControlsInstructions` method, or something similar, to [`src/directions.js`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/src/directions.js). This method could then be used with the button's click listener. This would require some careful state object management to ensure all visual interface elements are properly updated when the button is toggled (see [`src/reducers/index.js`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/src/reducers/index.js) and [`src/controls/instructions.js`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/src/controls/instructions.js)).